# Does the pair $(CX, X)$ have HEP?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-extension-property

Let $X$ be a space and $CX$ be the cone of $X.$ Then does $(CX, X)$ have homotopy extension property? If so, how do I show that?

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try showing $(CX, X)$ is a neighborhood deformation retract pair.

Comment: Dear @JHF do you mean $CX \times I$ deformation retracts to $(CX \times \{0\}) \cup (X \times I)\ $? But how do I show that? For $X = S^n,$ I can able do that in which case $CS^n \approx D^{n+1}.$ But for general $X$ I have no idea how to proceed? Could you please explain a bit more? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Phibetakappa JHF is suggesting that you show that there is a neighborhood $U$ of $X\times{0}$ in $CX$ such that $U$ deformation retracts  to $X$. See more about NDR [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/neighborhood+retract). It will then follow that $(CX, X)$ has HEP.